# SAS Counting Keywords Across Columns

Tags: sas

I have list of keywords; CORPORATE, REAL ESTATE, COMPETITION, TRADE, DISPUTE

I want to be able to count the number of occurrences these keywords appear between columns practice_area1—Practice_area10. Therefore, I want to scan across 10 columns and create new columns. Each new column will represent each of the keywords (above) and a count as a value e.g. Corporate 4

Once this statement has ran and we have our new columns I want to create a new variable “Practice Group” which is populated with the highest count of the new variables we have just created. The dataset below is an example of how the data should look:

[image]

Please could somebody offer me some advice of the best approach to do this?

Many Thanks

Chris

Comment: Please show what approach you have tried, and describe why you were unhappy with it.

Comment: I am currently have just be reading the functions available such as countw, scan and index function but I'm struggling in how to combine them together to make it work for this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is use makean array for all the columns which you want to check. Then do loop it through each column for the word you want to check by using count function and add the count in the loop.
Code below is checking for three columns and three values. You can apply this code to as many columns as you want.

```
data have(drop= i);
col1 = 'CORPORATE, REAL ESTATE, REAL ESTATE';
col2= 'CORPORATE, CORPORATE, TRADE, TRADE, TRADE, REAL ESTATE';
col3= 'TRADE, TRADE, DISPUTE,REAL ESTATE';
array col[*]  col1 - col3;
realestate=0;/*starting with zero*/
trade=0;
corporate= 0;
do i = 1 to 3;
realestate =realestate+count( col(i), 'REAL ESTATE');/* adding through the loop*/
TRADE =trade+count( col(i), 'TRADE');
CORPORATE= corporate+count( col(i), 'CORPORATE');
end;
run;
```

Comment: This works for me. Thanks a lot for getting back to me.